# How to work out a grammar if we know the language?

Tags: formal-languages

How could we work out a grammar if we know the language? How could we work out a grammar if we know the language that is restricted to a special kind like CFL or CSL? For example, we know $$L=\{a^nb^nc^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ How can we get the grammar? Is there any algorithm?

**PS**: Language here means at least the recursively enumerable one, or computably enumerable one.

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean by algorithm here, since there are uncountably many possible inputs (languages).

Comment: @Ramiro,thanks,I have edited the post to clarify what language means.

Having published the post,actually,I think this question seems to be related to Gold theorem of languaged identification,

Comment: If you intend to be asking a computability question, could you be more specific about the desired input/output? 

Comment: Regarding your edit, then do you intend that the question is:  given a Turing machine program that is known to enumerate a context free language, can we compute a grammar for it? 

Comment:  @Joel,thank you very much."the question is: given a Turing machine program that is known to enumerate a context free language, can we compute a grammar for it?",has been answered by Gold theorem of languag identification with "yes".And Even if we assumed, we have a Turing machine program that is known to enumerate a C.E. language, we can compute a grammar for it,by Gold theorem.But I do not know what the algorithm that works out the grammar is.Is there any algorithm(universal) that researcher has worked out?By the way,and can we make the condition on input more weak?

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining that there cannot be a computable procedure mapping any index of a c.e. set that happens to be a context-free-language to a grammar for that language.

Comment: There is a little quip associated with this.  The problem: "Given a language, find the grammar" is NP-complete.  Yet 5-year-old kids the world over do it (seemingly without effort).  Until the last few hundred years, they even did it without instruction...If you are young enough, you just hear the language and somehow you learn it.  **??Evidence that P=NP after all??**

Comment: 
















@Gerald,Could you give any reference for "The problem: "Given a language, find the grammar" is NP-complete. "? thank you.

The other part of your post is an important problem in a field other than computational complexity.Chomsky and a lot of scholar believe that the mechanism of natural language is innate.But I am not sure.










Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theorem.** There is no computable procedure which, given as
input a Turing machine program $e$ that enumerates a c.e. set that
happens to be a context-free language, outputs a context-free
grammar for that language.

Proof. Let us denote by $W_e$ the set enumerated by program $e$.
Suppose that there were such a computable procedure $e\mapsto
g(e)$, where $g(e)$ is a context-free grammar for $W_e$, if indeed
$W_e$ is a context-free language. (If $W_e$ is not context-free, then we do
not assume $g(e)$ is meaningful or even that it converges.)

We define a certain computable function $f$. For any program $e$, let $W_{f(e)}$ be the c.e. set defined as
follows. At first, we enumerate nothing into $W_{f(e)}$ until
$g(e)$ converges and outputs a context-free grammar. At this
point, if this grammar generates a non-empty language, then we
continue to enumerate nothing into $W_{f(e)}$ and thereby ensure that $W_{f(e)}$ is empty. Alternatively, if the language generated by the grammar $g(e)$ is empty, then we ensure that $W_{f(e)}=\{0\}$, containing a single
string. (Note that the emptiness problem for context-free grammars
is computably decidable.)

By the [recursion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem), there is a particular program $e$
such that $W_e=W_{f(e)}$. Since $W_{f(e)}$ is either empty or a
singleton, it follows that it is a context-free-language, and so
$g(e)$ is defined. But by construction, we have ensured that
$g(e)$ is a grammar for the empty language if and only if $W_e$ is
non-empty. And so for this program, $g(e)$ is not a grammar for
$W_e$. Contradiction. QED

Comment: It looks like the proof would be the same also for other grammars (e.g., regular languages/expressions) such that the emptiness problem is decidable. Is that right? Very interesting! Thanks!

Comment: Matteo, yes, I think that's right. 

Comment: This question has to be carefully decomposited into several ones:they have subtle difference,like the input,and are given different answers,especially to ones that have algorithms to find grammar.

Comment: I agree completely, and that was the meaning of my comment on your question. I think there will be versions of the question where an algorithm is possible. 